# Shapes incompatible with DenseNet transfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, densenet

I want to do transfer learning with DenseNet, and I found an example I want to work off of.

```
model_d=DenseNet121(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, 
input_shape=(224, 224, 3)) 

x=model_d.output

x= GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x= BatchNormalization()(x)
x= Dropout(0.5)(x)
x= Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) 
x= Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) 
x= BatchNormalization()(x)
x= Dropout(0.5)(x)

preds=Dense(7,activation='softmax')(x) 

model=Model(inputs=model_d.input,outputs=preds) 
model.summary()
```

So this is replacing the output of the original model with these layers. When I try to fit the model however, I get an incompatible shape error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible
```

However, looking at the model summary, I have no idea what the cause of this would be.

Comment: Seems like data label related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having only one class for prediction after the Softmax function but `preds=Dense(7,activation='softmax')(x)` expects to have 7 classes for prediction. Changing the `number 7 to 1` might solve your problem if you are predicting only 1 class. Also you should change your activation to `sigmoid`, otherwise having 1 neuron with `softmax` will always output 1

Note that this is just my assumption.

Comment: Thats werid though since the dataset seems to be properly partitioned: [here](https://imgur.com/a/hZgXlGD)